# IndexedDB error in PWA: Unable to open database file on disk

Tags: mobile-safari, indexeddb

In mobile Safari PWA, when calling `indexedDB.open`, I get an error "unable to open database file on disk".

The error does not occur in the mobile Safari browser when not added to the home screen as a PWA.

I can't tell the direct consequence of this, but the database often gets deleted on refresh after seeing this error.

Answer (score 2):

The error appears to be thrown in WebKit from [this line](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WebCore/Modules/indexeddb/server/SQLiteIDBBackingStore.cpp#L988) in SQLiteIDBBackingStore.cpp.

This issue is probably a bug in WebKit due to trying to open the database at the wrong time.

A possible workaround is to reduce the total number of IndexedDB databases, as described by @pesterhazy:

> ### Random exceptions when working with a large number of indexeddb databases (Safari)
>
> Sometimes Safari gets into a funky state, where exceptions like "Unable to open database file on disk" are thrown. Other exceptions related to indexeddb methods are also possible.
>
> When that happens, incredibly, hostname resolution starts failing. This seems unrelated but occurs at the same time, for unknown reasons.
>
> It's unclear what is causing this issue but I've been observing this problem mainly when there are many indexeddb databases for a given origin. The databases don't need to be opened for this bug to occur. You can fix the issue by deleting your local state.>
>
> You can work around this problem by only creating a small number of indexeddb databases.

https://gist.github.com/pesterhazy/4de96193af89a6dd5ce682ce2adff49a#random-exceptions-when-working-with-a-large-number-of-indexeddb-databases-safari